# Duration of Satellite orbit in the shadow of the Earth (elliptical orbit)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, orbital-motion, satellites

This question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108196/) calculated the time a satellite was in the shadow of the earth for a circular orbit. I was wondering if there was a way to do the same thing for an elliptical orbit.

Answer (score 4):

#### Only numerically

Yes, it is possible, but only with the use of  numerical methods. Instead of using

$$ t = \tau \frac{\theta}{2\pi} $$

(As the answer you referenced does) You must use a more general expression derived from Kepler’s second law:

$$ dt = \tau \frac{r^2}{2\pi ab} d\theta $$

Where $\tau$ is the orbital period, $a$ and $b$ are the semi-major and semi-minor axis of the orbit, and $r$ is a function of $\theta$ the true anomaly.  To solve for $t(\theta)$ requires numerical methods; there is no closed form solution except in the case of circular orbits.